# loss dashbord and termina can i get all my data if i do Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation

because of my mistake I do
`sudo apt-get purge python3.6`
then I lost my dashboard and terminal .
how to fix it and save all my data

anyone could help me